# Is there any subtle difference between the two forms of the imperfect subjuntive?

Tags: selección-de-palabras, verbos, subjuntivo, tiempos-verbales

The imperfect subjuntive has two forms. For example:

- Ojalá **viniera**.
- Ojalá **viniese**.

I think both has the same meaning. However, is there any subtle difference?

Comment: I've been wanting to ask this question too!

Comment: I'd say that the only difference is that the form ending in *-se* can be considered slightly more formal than the one ending in *-ra*; but otherwise (i.e., regarding the meaning) they are equivalent.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, there is no difference, at least in meaning.

Answer (score 4):

The advice I was always given was that there is no difference in the meaning, but to stick to one of them (ie don't mix and match) in a conversation/piece of text.

Comment: There's no problem switching between them.  You'll hear people even in formal Spanish alternate in the same phrase between them.

Answer (score 3):

There is no difference in meaning. I have found that the -ra endings are more common in Latin American Spanish and the -se endings are more common in European Spanish. So I would use the one that represents the type of Spanish you are trying to speak.

Comment: What about Mexico, which is in North America? If it falls in with Central and South America (which it often doesn't) you can just use the term "Latin American Spanish" instead.

Comment: Edited thus. I'd say it applies to Mexican Spanish as well.

Answer (score 0):

When used as subjunctive, there is no difference in meaning, except that as noted, the *-se* forms can carry in some places a slightly elevated sound, and regional/personal/phonetic differences will also affect the choice.  (*-se* frankly just *sounds* better on some verbs, on *-ra* on others).

But, do note that the *-ra* forms can also be used in the indicative, where they form the simple pluperfect: *Ya se levantara cuando recibió la llamada*.   Thus it is possible —although very *rebuscado* given how little *-ra* is used in the indicative— to have a sentence where *-se* is the only unambiguously subjunctive form: *El estudiante hacía lo que la profesora indicara* (does *indicara* mean *había indicado* or *indicase*?  Could be either.)